# Kafka deserialization error: failed to resolve class name. Class not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer in kafka but when I am sending events through kafka. It is giving me classNotFoundException even though I am using type mapping in my application.yml file.
Below is my producer side mapping of application.properties file:

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping= api:com.msb.config.json.ApiInsight
```

here is my consumer side mapping of application.yml file:

```
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: com.*
            type:
              mapping: api:com.msb.entity.ApiInsight
```

I am using type mapping after taking example from official docs of spring but I am getting the below error everytime.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.msb.config.json.ApiInsight]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.msb.config.json.ApiInsight
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:142) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.13.jar:2.9.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:103) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.13.jar:2.9.13]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:572) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.13.jar:2.9.13]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1426) ~[kafka-clients-3.2.3.jar:na]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.msb.config.json.ApiInsight
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
```

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72802278/9587830
Try to added it to trusted packages:
   props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES,"*");
   props.put(JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS,"false");